# Fahrenheit to Celsius converter. Verify int not char

Tags: c++, converters, temperature

Created a program to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius. Having trouble verifying if what the user input is an int. The problem I believe is the "if (!cin)" line.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
float f, c;
string choice;

do{
    cout << "Enter a Fahrenheit temperature to convert to Celsius:" << endl;
    cin >> f ;

    if ( !cin ) {
        cout << "That is not a number..." << endl;
    }

    else if (f < -459.67) {
        cout << "That is not a Fahrenheit temperature..." << endl;
    }

    if ( f >= -459.67) {
        c = (( f - 32) * 5.0)/9.0 ;
        cout << fixed ;
        cout << setprecision(2) << "Celsius temperature is: " << showpos << c << endl;
    }
    cout << "Would you like to convert another? If so, enter Yes" << endl;
    cin >> choice ;

}while ( choice == "Yes" || choice == "yes" );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the language you're using have a while loop?

Comment: Wouldn't that solve the problem?

Comment: Think you should post this under the C++ group.

Comment: Jeff, first time posting. I changed the tag to C++, is that it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you mean about your "Continue yes or no statement", So I've written a code that asks the user to type yes to confirm the conversion, otherwise no to enter a new Fahrenheit value. After the conversion, The program also asks the user to type yes if he/she wants another conversion, If the user types anything except "yes", The program will close.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool Continue = true;
    while (Continue == true)
    {
        double f, c;

        cout << endl << "Enter a Fahrenheit temperature to convert to Celsius:" << endl << endl;
        while (!(cin >> f))
        {
            cout << endl << "Invalid Input. " << endl << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        }
        while (f <= -459.67)
        {
            cout << "Invalid Input. " << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            cin >> f;
        }
        cout << endl << "Continue? Type yes to proceed conversion, Otherwise type no." << endl << endl;
        string confirmation;
        cin >> confirmation;
        while (confirmation != "yes" && confirmation != "no")
        {
            cout << endl << "Input not recognized. try again." << endl << endl;
            cin >> confirmation;
        }
        if (confirmation == "yes")
        {
            c = ((f - 32) * 5.0) / 9.0;
            cout << fixed;
            cout << endl << setprecision(2) << "Celsius temperature is: " << showpos << c << endl;

            cout << endl << "Another convertion? type yes to confirm. " << endl << endl;
            string cont;
            cin >> cont;
            if (cont != "yes")
            {
                Continue = false;
            }
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

You should use `while` loop, So the program won't stop asking until the user enters the correct data. Use `cin.clear();` to clear invalid data that the user inputted. And `cin.ignore();` to ignore any succeeding erroneous data. For example, '25tg', 'tg' character is ignored since it's not valid. '25' will be accepted.

Edits in my answer and code provided are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function to check if the input is numeric or not....

should be something like this:

```
    bool isFloat( string myString ) {
    std::istringstream iss(myString);
    float f;
    iss >> noskipws >> f; // noskipws considers leading whitespace invalid
    // Check the entire string was consumed and if either failbit or badbit is set
    return iss.eof() && !iss.fail(); 
}
```